# jQuery.get.done throwing TypeError (undefined property) when calling Steam API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeerror

I'm currently trying to teach myself JavaScript, mainly through documentation and trial and error. I'm struggling to figure out why this short code snippet always fails at reading the property of the response (the `key` value is omitted here):

```
$J.get("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=[key]&steamids=" + g_rgProfileData["steamid"]).done(function(res) {
    console.log(new Date(res["responseJSON"]["response"]["players"][0]["timecreated"] * 1000).toISOString().substring(0, 10));
});
```

The error message is always `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined`.

It is supposed to use [Steam's Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) to retrieve information about a player, then format the `timecreated` property (stored as Unix time) into a neat ISO 8601 string. A proper call to the API returns this as the `responseJSON` property:

```
{
  "response": {
    "players": [
      {
        "steamid": "76561198116637933",
        "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
        "profilestate": 1,
        "personaname": "GrunzJr",
        "commentpermission": 1,
        "profileurl": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/GrunzJr/",
        "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be2bd53ce0c7f024a30dbde1f46cbb441584dadb.jpg",
        "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be2bd53ce0c7f024a30dbde1f46cbb441584dadb_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/be/be2bd53ce0c7f024a30dbde1f46cbb441584dadb_full.jpg",
        "lastlogoff": 1587338437,
        "personastate": 1,
        "realname": "Near",
        "primaryclanid": "103582791433918461",
        "timecreated": 1385903721,
        "personastateflags": 0,
        "loccountrycode": "DE",
        "locstatecode": "01",
        "loccityid": 13305
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried delaying the second line with `window.setTimeout`, and that indeed fixes the issue, but it seems to be a very bad workaround and I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Any help on this problem is highly appreciated!

*First post on here, I hope I've made it correctly, but feedback for improvement is most welcome!*

Comment: Are you sure it won't be `res["response"]`?

Comment: Inside `$J.get.then(...` what does `console.log( res.responseJSON )` returns?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes, it's a bit weird, but after I added the timeout, it ran properly without any other changes.

Comment: @palaѕн That would output the JSON I posted as an example; depending on which ID was used to call the API and how much information is available to the caller, it might be shorter.

Comment: and what does `console.log( res.responseJSON.response )` returns? as you have mentioned `console.log( res.responseJSON )` returns a valid value, then how can you get `Cannot read property 'response' of undefined`?

Comment: @palaѕн It would output the array `"players"`. My assumption (I'm still a beginner at asynchronous JS) is that, somehow, the function inside `get.done` runs too early. If I add a timeout, no errors are thrown and I get a correctly formatted date.

Comment: As mentioned in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), "_When the Deferred is resolved, the doneCallbacks are called. Callbacks are executed in the order they were added._" so done call is only executed once the API call is resolved. There might be some other issue here, which I am not sure what is it. You have to check the docs of steampowered for more info.

Comment: Do a console.log and add the exact response object in the question, maybe as a screenshot

Comment: Maybe you can try using [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and see if that helps.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I hope [this is what you meant](https://i.imgur.com/W3cO47s.png). For some reason, that worked without trouble, I'm really confused about this whole thing.

Comment: Grr.. you just managed to crop the topmost line which would show if the data is `response` or `responseJSON` :)

Comment: I feel dumb now, the solution is indeed to remove `responseJSON`. Not sure why it did work when adding a timeout though. Thank you to both of you for your help nonetheless, sorry for wasting your time! :/

Comment: Just to be sure, should I leave this question as is, should I edit it in some way or what's the best course of action for me now?